# Call a CygWin function while still calling native Windows functions by default

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, mingw, windows-socket-api

I'm programming a server in Windows. I wanted to accept multiple connections on the server so I figured I could use CygWin's `fork()`. So I added the call to `fork()`, but ran into errors.

I realize these errors are caused by the fact that I want to call the Windows Socket API (WSA) socketing functions (e.g. `socket`, `bind`, `accept`) but when I compile with CygWin it's calling its own socketing functions.

**My question:** How can I use CygWin's `fork` but still use the WSA's `socket`, `accept`, and `bind`?

Comment: What `fork` is to do with that? You want the `winsock` functions, so include it and use them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The WSA functions are named the exact same as the CygWin socketing ones.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you've brought in Cygwin for no other reason than that you want `fork()`.  That's a crummy reason.  When you are writing for Windows, use Windows idioms, and forking is not among those.  Cygwin is most applicable to cases where you're trying to adapt existing POSIX-oriented software written to Windows.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can't find another good way to implement a server that accepts multiple clients...

Comment: Have you not considered using threads instead of completely separate processes?

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, actually... could you link to an example/tutorial?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Calling WinAPI in Cygwin apps should work.

Comment: I never said that it wouldn't, @yugr.  But that doesn't change the fact that CygWin is the wrong tool for developing Windows-specific programs.

Comment: @Lͬͬ̓̈́ͧͣ̽Oͭ̇͂͋̊̆͑ͧ͆͆ͫͬLͣͩ͗̾͐̚, requests for references to off-site tutorials are off-topic here.  Lest I be too indirect, however, I assert that spawning a separate *thread* to handle interaction with each client is a much more natural approach in Windows than is spawning a whole separate *process* for that purpose.   I am sure your Google-fu is strong enough to find resources discussing multi-threaded programming with the Windows API.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm not sure what "Windows-specific program" is. Using WinSock on occasion should not preclude one from using Cygwin (there's even an [entry](http://pipeline.lbl.gov/code/3rd_party/licenses.win/cygwin-doc-1.4/html/faq/index.html#faq.api.winsock) in Cygwin's FAQ about this).

Comment: @LOL Have you checked [the FAQ](http://pipeline.lbl.gov/code/3rd_party/licenses.win/cygwin-doc-1.4/html/faq/index.html#faq.api.winsock)?